# Postgres Invalid Reference to FROM Clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am having a hard time finding what I am doing wrong here.

```
    select * from prog_log as g0, order_line as g1, logstat as g2
    inner join channel as g3 on g3.chn_serial = g0.log_chn_id
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "g0"
    LINE 2: inner join channel as g3 on g3.chn_serial = g0.log_chn_id
                                                ^
    HINT:  There is an entry for table "g0", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

From what I've read I need to do some kind of join on g0, g1, and g2, but my database doesn't have a common column between them, so I can't do a join.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't mix the ancient implicit joins and explicit `JOIN` operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commas in Postgres bind more weakly than JOIN expressions; change each comma in the FROM clause to CROSS JOIN. See the [note in the relevant section of the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.6.4.2.1.1).